# Google Spreadsheet API on iPhone - Adding a new worksheet and a header

Tags: iphone

HI All,

Does anyone have the code for adding a spreadsheet with header using GDATA API.

I'm able to insert a new worksheet, but I'm not able to add a header to that.
Can some one please help me with that.

Thanks,
Srinivas.m

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about either platforms, but could you add a spreadsheet and then add the header afterwards?